# java map string string not increasing

Tags: java, dictionary, hashmap

```
Map<String, String> map = new HashMap<String, String>();             
     ObservableList<Object> row2 = FXCollections.observableArrayList();
           try {
            connected();
            String sql = "SELECT `20`.startdate, `20`.enddate, `20`.number FROM `20`";
             ResultSet rs = statement.executeQuery(sql);
             while(rs.next()){
                 String sd = rs.getString(3);
                 LocalDate std = rs.getDate(1).toLocalDate();
                 LocalDate end = rs.getDate(2).toLocalDate();
                  while (!std.equals(end)) {
                  std = std.plusDays(1);
                  String st = std.toString();
                  map.put(sd,st);
                  }

             }
             closed();}
              catch(Exception e){}
```

I create a new map. Then i put values to map. But map overwrites some values? Why? Not increasing

Comment: IF keys are same then it will override previous values

Comment: A more traditional approach to indentation would make your code more readable for people trying to help you.

Comment: some values are same

Answer (score 0):

A `Map` only stores one value for each key. If you want to store multiple values for the same key, you can use a `List<String>` or `Set<String>` as the value of the Map.

```
         Map<String, List<String>> map = new HashMap<String, List<String>>();   
         while(rs.next()){
             String sd = rs.getString(3);
             LocalDate std = rs.getDate(1).toLocalDate();
             LocalDate end = rs.getDate(2).toLocalDate();
             while (!std.equals(end)) {
                 std = std.plusDays(1);
                 String st = std.toString();
                 List<String> values = map.get(sd);
                 if (values == null) {
                     values = new ArrayList<String>();
                     map.put(sd,values);
                 } 
                 values.add(st);
             }

         }
```